# Rotating image makes the background dirty

Tags: python, rotation, pygame

I am working with pygame and want to make a car run inside a map, but when I call the `rotate` function, it makes a frame outside when the car rotates and covers the background (the black part of the image).
This is my code:

```
import pygame
import time

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load(image_file).convert()
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

    def rotate(self, angle) :
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, angle)

    def move(self, location) :
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

background = Background('image/raw_map.png', [0,0])
car = Car('image/car.png', [100,100])

pygame.display.flip()

for i in range(90) :
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    car.rotate(i)

    screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)
    screen.blit(car.image, car.rect)
    clock.tick(10)
    pygame.display.update()
```

And this is a picture when the car is rotating:

[image]

And another problem, my image has a clear background, but it still covers the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `convert_alpha` method if your image has a transparent background. If it has a unicolored background, you can call `set_colorkey` to make it transparent, but images converted with `convert_alpha` are blitted much faster, so I recommend this method.

I've also fixed your rotation code and added a few comments.

```
import pygame
# No need to import time, since you're using the pygame.time module.


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Call the convert method, then the image can be blitted faster.
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file).convert()
        # You can pass the location as the `topleft` argument.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)


class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # Call the `convert_alpha` method if the image has a transparent
        # background, otherwise you could use the `set_colorkey` method.
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha()
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)

    def rotate(self, angle):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, angle)
        # Get a new rect and pass the center of the previous rect. This
        # will keep the car centered.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def move(self, location):
        self.rect.topleft = location


pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

background = Background('image/raw_map.png', [0,0])
car = Car('image/car.png', [100,100])
angle = 0

done = False
while not done:
    # Need to handle events each frame or the window will freeze.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # Update the game.
    angle += 5
    car.rotate(angle)

    # Draw everything.
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background.image, background.rect)
    screen.blit(car.image, car.rect)
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you. After hours of worrying you solved it. I know thank you comments are bad but seriously this answer is helpful.